# SQL Joining single table where value does not exist

Tags: sql

I've tried a lot of techniques though I can't get the right answer.
For instance I have table with Country names and IDs. And I want to return only distinct countries that haven't used ID 3. Because if they have been mentioned on ID 2 or 1 or etc they still get displayed which I don't want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT test.country, test.id
FROM test
WHERE test.id LIKE 2
AND test.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT test.id FROM test WHERE test.id LIKE 3);
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand what you're looking for if you posted a sample table as well as desired results

Comment: For instance in table there are various countries: Poland, Russia, Germany and then IDs 1,2,3. But the table looks like this:
Poland 1
Russia 2
Russia 3
Germany 2
So in this case it will still show me Russia even though it has id 3

Comment: you want country not in not test ID...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.name 
FROM countries c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM countries c2 
  WHERE c1.name = c2.name
  AND c2.id = 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm now sure I understood your question, but if you want distinct countries where id is not 3, you just need this:

```
select distinct c.name from Countries
where c.id <> 3
```

Comment: This does not help still displays wrong information because there are same countries with ID 2 for instance so it still gets displayed

Answer (score 1):

you want to eliminate the countries having an ID of 3, not the ID's themselves...

```
SELECT Distinct t.country, T.ID
FROM test t
where not exists 
   (Select 1 from test t2 where t2.country = t.country and ID = 3)
```

Or

```
SELECT DISTINCT test.country, test.id
FROM test
WHERE test.country NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT test.country FROM test WHERE test.id =3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your situation is like,

[image: Table Data]

you need to result like ,
[image: Expected Result Data]

Then the Script will be like ,

```js
SELECT DISTINCT t1.country 
FROM test t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM test t2 
  WHERE t1.country = t2.country
  AND t2.id = 3
)
```